# How to make AUCTeX ignore syntax highlighting within environment

Tags: environments, verbatim, emacs, auctex

I have a problem with syntax highlighting in the Emacs editor using AUCTeX. The problem occurs in particular with the `Verbatim` environment from the `fancyvrb` package. Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
  $USER 
}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following screenshot:

[image]

The problem seems to be the `$` sign in the `Verbatim` environment, and AUCTeX believes that I have entered some math code that I have not yet terminated with an ending `$` sign..
Is there a way to tell AUCTeX to ignore syntax highlighting within a particular environment?

Comment: You can insert " %$" after `\end{Verbatim}` to fix the syntax highlight for the rest of the text. But that's not a solution, not even a workaround (because the syntax highlight is still broken in the verbatim environment).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what I add to my `Preferences.el` file (the `.emacs` equivalent for Aquamacs):

```
(setq LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local '("Verbatim" "lstlisting"))
```

This makes `Verbatim` and `lstlisting` behave like `verbatim`

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the same result with what included in \Sexpr{}?

Comment: @Francesco Sorry, but my knowledge of the Emacs arcana is not so deep. Maybe you can ask a fresh question.

Comment: Is there some similar setting for `\verb|$foo|`?

Comment: OK, found it myself. The list one has to set is `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local`

Answer (score -1):

```
M-x font-lock-mode
```

will disable syntax highlighting

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This switches off syntax highlighting for the whole buffer, not just the given environment.