# How can I fix AucTeX's syntax highlighting for the lstlisting environment when using optional arguments?

Tags: listings, emacs, auctex

The title really says it all, so I'll provide an example and a screenshot:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
For example, if we wished to create a predicate
  to determine if a node could mark itself
  (considering the \Algorithm{IndSet} problem),
  we could put~\autoref{lst:logic:pred-def}
\begin{lstlisting}[
float,
caption={caption}
label={label}
]
marked = v['marked']
neighbor_marked = any(map(lambda n: n['marked'], N))
return not (marked or neighbor_marked)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

It's worth noting that Emacs can't find the opener for the closing `]`.

Comment: I suppose writing all the options in the same line isn't an option, right?

Comment: @giordano It's technically an option, but not in the scope of this question.  My captions especially are often a little longer (no more than a sentence or two, but still) and benefit from line breaking for the VCS.  Labels also change frequently to avoid clashes, as do other options.  I was thinking maybe altering the regular expression to say something like `\\begin{lstlisting}([.*])?`, but I don't know where I'd put it (or if this would work, to be perfectly honest).

Comment: I see.  Unfortunately for the time being I have no solution, font locking isn't my specialty.  Anyway, try hacking `font-latex-set-syntactic-keywords`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntax highlighting of verbatim-like environments with optional arguments [was fixed upstream](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=32fc9bd6eab8c3eff29d6b16b51859d445c12fbf) and works out-of-the-box since AUCTeX 11.88.  There is no more need to apply the hack I previously suggested in the original answer (see below).

If you have [file parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Parsing-Files) enabled (which is highly recommended anyway, in order to exploit all features of AUCTeX) and you loaded `listings` package in your document, AUCTeX will automatically recognize `lstlisting` as a verbatim-like environment and highlight it correctly, including the optional argument.

> [image]

This works also if there is a pair of brackets inside the optional argument (for example the dialect of the language):

> [image]

or if the newline after the `\begin{environment}` is commented by a `%` character

> [image]

---

**Original answer** (needed only for AUCTeX 11.87 or previous versions)

Inside the `font-latex-set-syntactic-keywords` function, defined in `font-latex.el`, replace

```lisp
(add-to-list 'font-latex-syntactic-keywords
             `(,(concat "^[ \t]*\\\\begin *{\\(?:" verb-envs
                        "\\)}.*\\(\n\\)")
           (1 "|" t)))
```

with

```lisp
(add-to-list 'font-latex-syntactic-keywords
         `(,(concat
         "^[ \t]*\\\\begin *{\\(?:" verb-envs "\\)}[\t ]*\\(?:%.*\n[\t ]*\\)?"
         "\\(?:\\[[^\]\[]*\\(?:\\[[^\]\[]*\\][^\]\[]*\\)*\\]\\)?"
         "\\(\n\\)")
           (1 "|" t)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a nicer solution in this StackExchange post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111289/how-to-make-auctex-ignore-syntax-highlighting-within-environment)

Just add

```
(setq LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local '("Verbatim" "lstlisting"))
```

To your .emacs file to make AUCTeX to treat `lstlisting` as verbatim. It worked well for me and no need to hack the `auctex`-package source.

Comment: please fix the URL, it's broken

Comment: Should be fixed now. Sorry.

Comment: If file parsing is enabled, this is not necessary as the style file of `listing` package does it automatically.  `LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local` isn't meant to be customized by users, though it's not forbidden.  It is also worth mentioning that this answer works only because someone [installed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=32fc9bd6eab8c3eff29d6b16b51859d445c12fbf) the code suggested in the other answer to upstream AUCTeX.